# How to run Apache Crunch application without a Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-crunch

I heard, that Apache Crunch is a facade and it can run applications without a Hadoop. Is this true?

If yes, then how to do that?

In [Apache Crunch Getting Started](https://crunch.apache.org/getting-started.html) the very first example includes hadoop command:

```
$ hadoop jar target/crunch-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT-job.jar <in> <out>
```

Is it possible to omit `hadoop`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you misunderstood that you don't need a Hadoop **cluster**. Hive, Pig, Spark can all be ran locally, or filesystems other than HDFS.

From as much as I can know about the library, you do, however, need the Hadoop API (which is what `hadoop jar` will load for you).

In other words, you could set the input and output directories to a local `file://` path to get around needing HDFS.

You can `export CLASSPATH` yourself to include Hadoop libraries, and run `java jar` to run the JAR